# Can my tamping method damage the basket or portafilter?

Tags: tamping

I have developed the following tamping method:

1. press the grinds with the tamper without much force, to smoothen it
2. leave the tamper in the basket
3. holding the tamper and the portafilter together, whack the silicone tamping mat with the portafilter so that the inertia + my pressure drive the tamper into the grinds.

Can damage my equipment in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, by the majority of baristas, the recommended method to tamp is this:

1. safely hold the basket (with the portafilter)
2. fill and tamp the grounds using appropriate force (5–20 kgf)
3. make a circular movement (180–360°) with the tamper to smooth the surface

---

Regarding your question, any kind of shock may be harmful for your gadgets in the long run.